# MYSQL & is not statement

Tags: mysql

Struggling to write a view where it populates a dropdown box from a table.

The dropdown will only show items that have not already been created. In my case its fields in a farm cost programme.

`$`

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[cmbPopulateFieldsnotcosted]
    AS SELECT 
    fieldID,
    fieldName,
    fieldLocation,
    fieldSize,
    fieldHistory
    FROM [fieldDetails]
    where fieldDetails.fieldID not in fieldCosts.fieldID
    inner join fieldCosts.fieldID = fieldDetails.fieldID
```

`$`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upDzM.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbgid.png)

The two images show the errors I am getting.

Any help would be appreciated.

Also to give more information, when i already have a field that has had costs added I do not want to be able to add more costs for it. Rather just update it, hence wanting to write this view to allow me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a in clause you should provide and array ( or a subselect result )

but in your case you are using a join so you should use !=

```
  CREATE VIEW [dbo].[cmbPopulateFieldsnotcosted]
      AS SELECT 
      fieldID,
      fieldName,
      fieldLocation,
      fieldSize,
      fieldHistory
      FROM [fieldDetails]
      where fieldDetails.fieldID !=  fieldCosts.fieldID
      inner join fieldCosts.fieldID = fieldDetails.fieldID
```

(because in this case the set is managed  by the join and not by a in clause)

*Anyway you are using a notation with square [] brackets  that are not proper or mysql .. (seems sqlServer )*

Comment: Hi,

Cheers for that.

Sorry should have said using mysql through VS2015 and its being a right pain. 

I seem to not be able to save my views even in the programme.

When I create the view it is giving me the square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a MySQL question - it's a MSSQL question.

Try this:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[cmbPopulateFieldsnotcosted]
AS SELECT 
fieldID,
fieldName,
fieldLocation,
fieldSize,
fieldHistory
FROM [fieldDetails]
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM [fieldCosts] 
                  WHERE fieldDetails.fieldID = fieldCosts.fieldID)
```

You could also use an outer join:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[cmbPopulateFieldsnotcosted]
AS SELECT 
fieldID,
fieldName,
fieldLocation,
fieldSize,
fieldHistory
FROM [fieldDetails]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [fieldCosts] ON (fieldDetails.fieldID = fieldCosts.fieldID)
WHERE fieldCosts.fieldID IS NULL
```